# Генератор inline-кнопок в Telegram боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, генераторы

У меня возникла необходимость генерировать инлайн кнопки исходя из данных списка типа: "запеканка, сырники, яичница"

```
@bot.message_handler(regexp="Готово")
def done(message):
        data = (open('/Users/user/Desktop/CODE/rbot/data/%s.txt' % user, 'r')).readline() #тут создается файл с id пользователя
        choice = data.split()
        recipes = open('/Users/user/Desktop/CODE/rbot/data/recipe_key.txt', 'r').readlines() # файл с ключами к вабранным ингредиентам и в следующей строке названия возможных блюд из этих ингредиентов
        for index, line in enumerate(recipes):
            if choice == line.split():
                 
                # тут просто кнопки клавиатуры
              
                markup_reply = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
                item_choise = types.KeyboardButton('Выбрать другие продукты')
                item_next = types.KeyboardButton('Выбрать готовый рецепт')
                markup_reply.add(item_choise, item_next)
                
           
                # в тестовом режиме выводятся названия возможных рецептов строкой в сообщении (recipes[index+1])
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, recipes[index+1], reply_markup = markup_reply)
                erase = (open('/Users/artamonov/Desktop/CODE/rbot/data/%s.txt' % user, 'w'))
                erase.close() # чистим файл

                generateButton = recipes[index+1].split()
                generateindex = recipes[index+2].split()

                keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

# далее нужно сгенерировать кнопки по подобию button_0

                for item in generateButton: #цикл который будет генерировать...
                    
                    button_0 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='%s' %generateButton[0], callback_data= '%s' %generateindex[0])



                keyboard.add(button_0, button_1, ...) # сюда нужно получить имена всех сгенерированных кнопок

                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберете основные ингредиенты:", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def default_test(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button_first = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Запеканка", callback_data="Запеканка")
    button_second = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Сырники", callback_data="Сырники")
    button_third = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Яичница", callback_data="Яичница")
    keyboard.add(button_first,button_second, button_third )
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет! Нажми на кнопку и получишь рецепт.", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: Как создавать кнопки я знаю. Вопрос был совершенно в другом.

Answer (score 0):

3 дня бился с проблемой и нашел решение:

```
markup_reply = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
                item_choise = types.KeyboardButton('Выбрать другие продукты')
                item_next = types.KeyboardButton('Выбрать готовый рецепт')
                markup_reply.add(item_choise, item_next)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, recipes[index+1], reply_markup = markup_reply)
                erase = (open('.../CODE/rbot/data/%s.txt' % user, 'w'))
                erase.close()

                generateButton = recipes[index+1].split()
                generateindex = recipes[index+2].split()
                try: # количество кнопок каждый раз разное, а генерировать переменные кнопок я не умею и не уверен что вообще возможно. Поэтому я заготовил 12 на всякий случай. Через try-except ошибки возникать не будут.
                    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                    button_0 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='%s' %generateButton[0], callback_data= '%s' %generateindex[0])
                    button_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='%s' %generateButton[1], callback_data= '%s' %generateindex[1])
                    button_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='%s' %generateButton[2], callback_data= '%s' %generateindex[2])
                    button_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='%s' %generateButton[3], callback_data= '%s' %generateindex[3])
                    button_4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='%s' %generateButton[4], callback_data= '%s' %generateindex[4])
                    button_5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='%s' %generateButton[5], callback_data= '%s' %generateindex[5])
                    button_6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='%s' %generateButton[6], callback_data= '%s' %generateindex[6])
                    button_7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='%s' %generateButton[7], callback_data= '%s' %generateindex[7])
                    button_8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='%s' %generateButton[8], callback_data= '%s' %generateindex[8])
                    button_9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='%s' %generateButton[9], callback_data= '%s' %generateindex[9])
                    button_10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='%s' %generateButton[10], callback_data= '%s' %generateindex[10])
                    button_11 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='%s' %generateButton[11], callback_data= '%s' %generateindex[11])
                except:
                    pass
            
                for i, item in enumerate(generateindex):
                    f = 'button_' + str(i)
                    keyboard.add(eval(f)) # тут и было решение: генерируем строковые названия переменных кнопок и через eval запихиваем их как аргументы добавленной клавиатуры. 
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет', reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: Да, я видел дату ответа, но раз уж вопрос подняли - скажу. Использовать `eval()` вообще плохо, он небезопасен да еще и медленный. И вообще, для таких случаев `list` подходить просто идеально. И неограниченное число кнопок, и цикл на создании, и уберешь `eval()` - всё что нужно :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно так попробовать:

```py
list_button_name = ['button 1', 'button 2', 'button 3', 'button 4']

buttons_list = []
for item in list_button_name:
    buttons_list.append([InlineKeyboardButton(text=item, callback_data=item)])

keyboard_inline_buttons = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=buttons_list)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]